# How to get all record from report_table where user(user_table) belongs to an organization A

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on an existing database and I'm trying to get all the records from `reports` table that belongs to an organization of the logged in user.

The `users` table has `organization_id` column and the `reports` table has `user_id` column.

The logged in user John Doe belongs to an organization Apple and might or might not have records in `reports` table. They are also other users from Apple organization that have records in `report`. I want to retrieve all the records that belongs to organization Apple based on the logged in user John Doe.

Comment: Can you provide (as text) your table structure and data?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? What have you tried? Table structure, sample data, and expected results would all make this much clearer and easier to answer. However I expect it can be done entirely in SQL using JOINs so you can remove the PHP tag at the same time as you edit the extra information into the question. Thanks.